# React Native A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npx

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, npx

When I try to build signed bundle I get this error.

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npx''

How can I solve this issue ? Thanks.

```
"npx": "^10.2.2",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2"
```

Comment: How did you solve the issue? Can you please post an answer in detail?

Comment: @Shaharyar I created new project with npx and then resolved.

Comment: I am running the command with `-x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` param and it's not coming now. Don't know how it solves

Comment: @Shaharyar I mean you should create project with  npx create-react-app your-app and then this issue will be resolve.

Comment: Actually, this is an existing project.